# Trying to understand when you can and cannot preserve an index-column with a self merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

Using this sample df:

```
lotrd = pd.DataFrame({'title':['FOTR', 'TTT', 'TRTK'],'sequel':[618346260,7171994,np.nan]},index=[618346252,618346260,7171994])
lotrd.index.name='id'
```

which outputs:
[image]

This code

```
print(pd.merge(lotrd, lotrd, left_on='sequel', right_on='id', right_index=True))
```

yields:
[image]

But if I simply reverse the left/right_on= sides (and _index=True side), i.e.,

```
print(pd.merge(lotrd, lotrd, left_on='id', right_on='sequel', left_index=True))
```

I get an error:
[image]

I can, however, omit the left_index=True arg

```
print(pd.merge(lotrd, lotrd, left_on='id', right_on='sequel'))
```

and get this:
[image]

But that doesn't preserve the index-column.

Is there actually something wrong with pairing an index-column merge with left_on= and left_index=True, or am I overlooking something else? I'm looking for any general guidance (as I can't find much elsewhere) on what the implications are for changing the ordering of inputs for self joins.

Answer (score 1):

You can get use of **[`pandas.DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)** to keep both indexes :

```
>>> print(pd.merge(lotrd.reset_index(), lotrd.reset_index(),  left_on='id', right_on='sequel'))

        id_x title_x   sequel_x       id_y title_y     sequel_y
0  618346260     TTT  7171994.0  618346252    FOTR  618346260.0
1    7171994    TRTK        NaN  618346260     TTT    7171994.0
```

Comment: Definitely a useful workaround! It's still curious to me though that you only seem to be able to merge, keeping an index as index via left/right_index=True, if you merge but specify right_index=True. I've experimented with this even in situations that aren't self joins, and Python consistently has an issue with trying to do use left_index=True for index-preservation purposes.